# What was the population of Muslims in the Indian subcontinent in 1800 AD?

Tags: india, population, muslims

[This](http://www.kashmirherald.com/featuredarticle/indiacensus-prn.html) article states:

> To put it in broader perspective, Muslim population has steadily grown
>   from 13% in 1800 to 16% in 1850 to 20% in 1900 to 25% in 1947 and
>   anywhere between 30 to 33% today taking into account the geographical
>   area of pre-partitioned India. These statistics are available from
>   various sources.

It doesn't provide any reference that I can check.

[This book](https://books.google.com.bd/books?id=75FlxDhZWpwC&pg=PA163&lpg=PA163&dq=population+of+Muslims+in+the+Indian+subcontinent+in+1800+AD&source=bl&ots=Nx5xO9CaFl&sig=gOkpkLFUuU1_5Ojxqb7jfNF_FV0&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=population%20of%20Muslims%20in%20the%20Indian%20subcontinent%20in%201800%20AD&f=false) estimates that India's population may have been 185 million in 1800 AD.

[image: Muslim population in 1800 AD]

But it doesn't give any estimate of the Muslim population.

**13% of 185 million = 24.05 million.** Is it a correct estimate?

According to most widely accepted estimate by historians, What was the population of Muslims in the Indian subcontinent in 1800 AD?

(If such data is not available, I would be happy with estimates of between 1800 and 1850)

Comment: [Poplstat](http://www.populstat.info/Asia/indiac.htm) estimates 255000,0 in 1800 which is probably within the margin of error for your estimate. [ 1803: India's population is 200 million.](http://www.thelatinlibrary.com/imperialism/notes/indianchron.html) cites no source, but offers a similar number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Muslim proportion in "undivided India" - today's India, Pakistan and Bangladesh - has risen from 21% in the late 19th century to about 31½% today, but there can be little doubt that the rate of increase was slower in the C19, much of the 20th-century growth being concentrated in the area now forming Pakistan which saw exceptional agricultural development from the 1880s. This is consistent with experience elsewhere: past populations were on the whole less mobile and less subject to rapid economic transformation than in recent times.

A tentative reconstruction for c.1850 based on McEvedy's breakdown into today's areas ([Atlas of world population history](https://books.google.com.ph/books/about/Atlas_of_World_Population_History.html?id=WZkYAAAAIAAJ&redir_esc=y), Penguin 1978) suggests about 11 million Muslims in what is now Pakistan, 23m in today's India and 15m in Bangladesh (against 15m, 29m and 19m respectively in 1901) - in all roughly a fifth. In 1800 with a total population of 190-200m we're probably looking at a Muslim contribution of 35-40 million (about a fifth of them in Pakistan, a half in India and 30% in Bangladesh) as there is no reason to assume any disproportionate advance in areas of predominantly Muslim settlement. It's certainly a good deal more than 25m or the first source's 13%, numbers derived from extending 20th-century trends into the 19th where they simply don't apply.

Of the three present-day states, Bangladesh has shown the least change in its share of the subcontinent's Muslim population, rising to 32% in the 1960s before falling back to 27% today: population movements at the time of partition raised Pakistan's share from under a quarter to more than a third while lowering India's from 45% to 35%: today Pakistan and India each contribute 36-37%.

Answer (score 9):

India's first (*& [most reliable](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2339124?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents)*) census was from 1867 to 1871, known as the [**1872 Census of India**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1871_Census_of_India). The Government of India confirms this in their [**census history**](http://censusindia.gov.in/Data_Products/Library/Indian_perceptive_link/History_link/censushistory.htm). So, there is no data prior to this census, hence all numbers below are estimates.

In terms of estimated population, **circa 1800 to 1850**, *[The Cambridge Economic History of India, Volume 2, c.1751–c.1970](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/cambridge-economic-history-of-india/57937CDBBE6F4B5C474E0A7A59697AF3#fndtn-information)* provides estimates on p.466, Table 5.1 (*the range is from different authors' estimates*):

- **1800: 157 to 214 million**
- **1850: 183 to 247 million**

I cannot find any information on estimates of Muslim population circa 1800 to 1850, but hopefully the range of total population might come in useful.

Your estimated Muslim population of 13% is extremely close to the Government of India's (2001 Census Data) estimate: **[13.4%](http://censusindia.gov.in/Census_And_You/religion.aspx)**.

Comment: Upvote for splendid research, summary and answer.

Comment: Thanks, I was actually surprised I couldn't get _better sources_ on Muslims in India circa 1800-1850.

Answer (score 1):

The graph in [this answer to another question](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/33640/what-was-the-population-of-indian-subcontinent-in-1000-ad/35315#35315) puts the population of the Indian subcontinent in 1800 at around 190 million. 13% of that would be 24.7 million, which corresponds very closely to your estimate of 24.05 million. So "25 million" is probably the right order of magnitude.